# Identity-Matrix Normal form of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm confused about the following.

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear isomorphism and let $\nu=(v_1,...v_n)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\omega=(w_1,...,w_n)$ the basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $w_j:=\phi(v_j)$. Now if I look at the matrix which represent $\phi$ with respect to the basis $\nu$ and $\omega$ I get that this matrix is the identity matrix. But this can't be true. Where is my mistake?
(If this would be true, then any isomorphism would have determinant 1, since the determinant of a linear map is independent of the chosen repr. matrix)

On the other hand I read that every linear mapping $A: 
\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ has a normal form 
$
\text{diag}(1,...,1,0,...,0)
$,
where there are r=rank(A) many 1's 
. Is this even true then? And if so, what would be a proof?(when reading this I thought that the proof is to choose a basis as above and then add linearly independ vectors of the kernel of A, but I guess this is wrong)

Comment: The matrix representation of a linear map is the identity iff the map is the identity map. And for the second question, the matrix would look like that if the map is not injective.

Comment: What you say in your comment is false as in this case we're talking about a matrix representation of a linear map with respect to **two different basis**  and not wrt the same basis both in the domain and in the codomain...

Comment: Why would the linear transformation be the identity?  This is in no way clear.

Comment: I did not say that the linear transformation itself is the identity. I just said, that w.r. to the above basis the representing matrix is the identity matrix. (If we look at the images of the basis vectors $v_j$ under $\phi$ and then express these images as linear combination of the basis vectors $w_j$, then one gets: $\phi(v_j)=w_j$, so the corresponding repr. matrix is just the identity-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake.

What probably confuses you is that well... what's the point of having other non singular matrices if you can express isomorphisms via the identity matrix?

The problem is that those matrices express isomorphisms for bases that are non correspondent one by one under that isomorphism.

Summarizing, the "bizarre" thing about this isomorphism is that you have selected a very special base for the image: a base composed by the images of the base of the dominion.

Comment: Of course the basis for the image is special, but what if I change the basis in the image with a transformation matrix say $T$. Then we would have $det(T*A*T^{-1})=det(A)=1$ for $A$ the repr. matrix of $\phi$ wr. to $\nu, \omega$. And also the eigenvalues of $\phi$ would be just $1$, since they are independent of the choice of repr. matrix. With this argument any isomorphism would have determinant 1 and all eigenvalues equal to 1.

Comment: You are not taking into account that the bases are different and this is not an endomorphism so the transformation matrix in the new pair of bases is not $T^{-1}AT$ but $W^{-1}AT$ where $W$ is the transformation matrix between bases in the image.

Comment: In other words: that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues doesn't hold in this case because you don't have similar matrices.

Comment: Good point. That makes sense.